# de Rham cohomology types

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Can a space have a de Rham cohomology other than $\mathbb{R}^n$? I have yet to see an example. (i.e. can a space have k$^{th}$ cohomology group = n torus or something?)

Answer (score 3):

de Rham cohomology groups are actually real vector spaces, so I don't think a space can have an $n$-torus as its cohomology.

If you're asking whether all spaces have the same de Rham cohomology as $\mathbb{R}^n$, the answer is no. For example $H^1(S^1)=\mathbb{R}$ while $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)=0$.